# PowerShell Azure New-AzureRmVM not responding

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to automate VM creation in Azure environment. Everything is working fine, even the VM is getting created with this script, but the script is getting hanged and every time I have to use Ctrl+Alt+Delete to end the script. While putting debugger I am seeing the execution is getting hanged on the last line of my code. Rest of all the line is working fine only while coming to the last line its getting hanged.

```
$result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose
```

I put the following code to read the status of VM creation. I want to read the status and update user accordingly. Unfortunately control is not coming here at all.

```
if($result.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {  
$result
Write-Verbose ('VM named ''{0}'' is now ready, you can connect using username: {1} and password: {2}' -f $VMName, $username, $password)
} else {
    Write-Error 'Virtual machine was not created successfully.'
}
```

Following are the entire script. Any suggestions are welcome to get rid of this.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Azure Automation"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(413, 320) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.TopMost=$true


#$objForm.AutoScaleDimensions= New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6F 13F) 
#$objForm.AutoScaleMode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font

# Project Name Label
$lblProjectName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $lblProjectName.AutoSize = $true;
 $lblProjectName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(23, 55)
 $lblProjectName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(83, 13)
 $lblProjectName.TabIndex = 0
 $lblProjectName.Text = "Project Name"
 $objForm.Controls.Add($lblProjectName)

 #Project Name TextBox
 $txtProjectName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
 $txtProjectName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(151, 55)
 $txtProjectName.MaxLength = 9
 $txtProjectName.Name = "txtProjectName"
 $txtProjectName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(146, 20);
 $txtProjectName.TabIndex=1
 $objForm.Controls.Add($txtProjectName)

 #Label VM Size
$lblVMSize = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblVMSize.AutoSize = $true
$lblVMSize.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(23, 97)
$lblVMSize.Name = "lblVMSize";
$lblVMSize.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(53, 13)
$lblVMSize.TabIndex = 2
$lblVMSize.Text = "VM Size"
$objForm.Controls.Add($lblVMSize)

 #Combo VM Size
 $cmbVMSize = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' 
 $cmbVMSize.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(151, 94)
 $cmbVMSize.Name = "cmbVMSize";
 $cmbVMSize.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(146, 21);
 $cmbVMSize.TabIndex = 3;
 $cmbVMSize.SuspendLayout() 
 [void]$cmbVMSize.Items.Add('Standard_A0') 
 [void]$cmbVMSize.Items.Add('Standard_A1') 
 [void]$cmbVMSize.Items.Add('Standard_A2') 
 [void]$cmbVMSize.Items.Add('Standard_A3') 
 [void]$cmbVMSize.Items.Add('Standard_A4') 
 $cmbVMSize.ResumeLayout($false) 
 [void]$objForm.Controls.Add($cmbVMSize) 

  #Lable OS
 $lblOS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $lblOS.AutoSize = $true;
 $lblOS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(23, 143)
 $lblOS.Name = "lblOS";
 $lblOS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(106, 13)
 $lblOS.TabIndex = 4
 $lblOS.Text = "Operating System"
 [void]$objForm.Controls.Add($lblOS)

  #Combo OS
 $cmbOS = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' 
 $cmbOS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(151, 140)
 $cmbOS.Name = "cmbOS";
 $cmbOS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(146, 21);
 $cmbOS.TabIndex = 5;
 $cmbOS.SuspendLayout() 
 [void]$cmbOS.Items.Add('Windows Server') 
 [void]$cmbOS.Items.Add('Ubuntu Server') 
 [void]$cmbOS.Items.Add('Red Hat Enterprise Linux') 
 [void]$cmbOS.Items.Add('SQL Data Center') 
 [void]$cmbOS.Items.Add('Oracle Data Center') 
 $cmbOS.ResumeLayout($false) 
 [void]$objForm.Controls.Add($cmbOS) 

  #Lable DB
 $lblDB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $lblDB.AutoSize = $true;
 $lblDB.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(23, 185)
 $lblDB.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(61, 13)
 $lblDB.TabIndex = 6
 $lblDB.Text = "Database"
 [void]$objForm.Controls.Add($lblDB)

   #Combo DB
 $cmbDB = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' 
 $cmbDB.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(151, 182)
 $cmbDB.Name = "cmbDB";
 $cmbDB.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(146, 21);
 $cmbDB.TabIndex = 7;
 $cmbDB.SuspendLayout() 
 [void]$cmbDB.Items.Add('SQL2014-WS2012R2') 
 [void]$cmbDB.Items.Add('SQL2014SP1-WS2012R2') 
 $cmbDB.ResumeLayout($false) 
 [void]$objForm.Controls.Add($cmbDB) 

 # Submit Button
$submitbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$submitbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(26, 249)
$submitbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$submitbutton.Text = "Submit"
$submitbutton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $false;
$submitbutton.TabIndex = 8
$submitbutton.Add_Click($Button_Click)
[void]$objForm.Controls.Add($submitbutton)


$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
#$objForm.ShowDialog()
 [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($objForm)

 $Button_Click = 
{
    #Assign unique number 
    $randomNumber = Get-Random -minimum 1 -maximum 1000 
    #Value taken from UI 
    $ProjectName = $txtProjectName.Text.ToLower();
    $VMSize = $cmbVMSize.SelectedItem
    $OfferName = $cmbDB.SelectedItem
    #Internal Value
    $Location = "westeurope"
    $ResourceGroupName = $ProjectName + $randomNumber
    $StorageName = $ProjectName + "storage"
    $StorageSku = "Standard_LRS"
    $InterfaceName = $ResourceGroupName + "ServerInterface"
    $VNetName = $ResourceGroupName + "VNet"
    $SubnetName = "Default"
    $VNetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
    $VNetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
    $TCPIPAllocationMethod = "Dynamic"
    $DomainName = $ProjectName
    $VMName = $ResourceGroupName + "VM"
    $ComputerName = $ResourceGroupName + "Server"   
    $OSDiskName = $VMName + "OSDisk"
    $PublisherName = "MicrosoftSQLServer"    
    $Sku = "Standard"
    $Version = "latest"


    ## Main Logic to connect VM
    # Step 1: Install Azure PowerShell
    Try
{
    $objForm.Close()
    Login-AzureRmAccount
    #Start-Sleep -s 10
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location
    Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability $ResourceGroupName
    $StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageName -SkuName $StorageSku -Kind "Storage" -Location $Location

    if(-not $StorageAccount)
    {  
    throw "Unable to find storage account '$StorageName'. Cannot continue."
    }
    # Enable verbose output and stop on error 
    # Create the VNET
    Write-Verbose 'Creating Virtual Network'  
    $SubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName -AddressPrefix $VNetSubnetAddressPrefix
    $VirtualNetwork = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AddressPrefix $VNetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SubnetConfig
    # Create the NIC
    Write-Verbose 'Creating Public IP'  
    $PublicIpAddress = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AllocationMethod $TCPIPAllocationMethod -DomainNameLabel $DomainName
    $InterfaceNic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -SubnetId $VirtualNetwork.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $PublicIpAddress.Id
    # Credentials 
    Write-Verbose 'Entering Credentials'  
    $username = "indmukhe"
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "P@ssword" –AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = new-object management.automation.pscredential $username,$password
    #$Credential = Get-Credential 
    # Specify the VM name and size
    Write-Verbose 'Creating VM Config'  
    $VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Windows -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate #-TimeZone = $TimeZone
    $VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $InterfaceNic.Id
    $OSDiskUri = $StorageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $OSDiskName + ".vhd"
    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $OSDiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -Caching ReadOnly -CreateOption FromImage 
    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName $PublisherName -Offer $OfferName -Skus $Sku -Version $Version
    Write-Verbose 'Creating VM...' 
    $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose
    if($result.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {  
    $result
    Write-Verbose ('VM named ''{0}'' is now ready, you can connect using username: {1} and password: {2}' -f $VMName, $username, $password)
    } else {
        Write-Error 'Virtual machine was not created successfully.'
    }  


}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName

    write-Error $ErrorMessage
    write-Error $FailedItem  

}
Finally
{      

    $objForm.Dispose()
    exit 1
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
if($result.ProvisioningState -eq "Succeeded")
{  
    Write-Verbose ('VM named ''{0}'' is now ready, you can connect using    username: {1} and password: {2}' -f $VMName, $username, $password)
} 
else
{
    Write-Error 'Virtual machine was not created successfully.'
}
```