# Azure power shell Virtual machine creation issue

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure power shell world. I am trying to create power shell script to automate VM creation. All my script running well, VM is getting created as well, but it’s getting hanged on its last line. So even though the virtual machine gets created my power shell script is keep on running. Please advise me how to address this issue.

```
Write-Verbose 'Creating VM...'  
$result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $vm
if($result.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {  
 Write-Verbose $result.Status
 Write-Verbose ('VM named ''{0}'' is now ready, you can connect using  username: {1} and password: {2}' -f $vmName, $adminUsername, $adminPassword)
} 
  else {
Write-Error 'Virtual machine was not created successfully.'
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code?

Comment: looking at this piece of code no one can conclude anything. So, plz provide the whole script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078219/powershell-azure-new-azurermvm-not-responding

Comment: Please refer this url to get complete code.

Answer (score 0):

you can take another way, to verify the state of the VM

```
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $vm
if((Get-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName).Status -eq "ReadyRole"){
  #Do something awesome here :)
}
```

and have a look at: https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-create-an-azure-vm-with-powershell/

Comment: How come you are expecting to get an RM vm status with Get-azureVM command ? Why service name parameter ??

Comment: Are u sure ? It should be get-azurermvm

Comment: (Get-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).StatusCode this gives result "OK" but (Get-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Statuses doesn't yelds any result

Comment: @Indrajit what does `Get-AzureRmVM -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName` result?

Comment: One observation.  You may find that I have created Win form designed in power shell. So while I am running the script the win form appears to take the input and based on the input the script runs. Now while I am running the script without any GUI (I am passing my hard coded value) it’s not getting hanged but it’s while I am running with GUI.

Comment: @Eldo.ObThe main issue I am facing is when I am trying to execute the script the control is getting hanged on this line.                                $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine

Even though the virtual machine is getting created and working fine. To stop the execution, I am always using Ctrl+Alt+Delete function. Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

return type of $result will be a psobject. After successful VM creation the output will be in below format

> $result[0] = "Provisioning succeeded"
>
> $result[1] = "VM running"

So, try this-

```
if($result.ProvisioningState -eq "Succeeded")
{  
    Write-Verbose ('VM named ''{0}'' is now ready, you can connect using    username: {1} and password: {2}' -f $VMName, $username, $password)
} 
else
{
    Write-Error 'Virtual machine was not created successfully.'
}
```